# Area 51 Proposal: Math Challenges

Tags: discussion, voting, area51

On September 1st, I started a proposal on Area 51, for users to share, discuss and answer mathematical  challenges that they have. I did this because I felt that these types of problems have no place in any of the current, relevant sites about mathematics/puzzles. If you want to envision the proposed site a little better, this is essentially a Mathematical Puzzling site, where the asker of the question knows the answer to it.

For example, [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net) is a site for professionals, [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com) is a site for users to discuss any genuine problems they have that they couldn't solve, and [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), of course, does not welcome [mathematical questions](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4898/revisiting-the-math-question-or-math-puzzle-policy), but only mathematical puzzles, which I think, is entirely appropriate for such a site.

I have made this post in Mathematics Meta a while ago, but I'm putting this in MathOverflow Meta as well to tell this to users who are not really active on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

**The link to the proposal is [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/119894/math-challenges)!**

> We are currently in the Definition phase. To bypass that, we need at least 60 followers and at least 40 questions with a score of at least 10. This must be done in four months, so the deadline is January 1st.

Our current progress is at 67 followers (yay) and only 5 questions with a score of at least 10.

Here are some further stats:

- we need at least 10 more questions to fulfill the 40 mark
- we need at least 280 upvotes in total for all of the questions combined - this does not take into account of any downvotes
- we have only 70 days left (so a minimum of 4 upvotes/day).

70 days might sound a lot, but given the number of votes to be achieved, the target is very tight.

---

So, if you are interested in this proposal, please vote on the current example questions, and better still, it would be amazing if you could post some more!

- to do this, you will first need to login to Area 51
- then click on your profile pic and then click on send email verification
- after you have verified your email, you will get the 50 rep needed to upvote questions

If you have any questions about this proposal, please take a look at the five discussion questions on Area 51 about the proposed site, from what types of questions are allowed to how we could manage non-original questions.

Thank you!

Comment: Done.............